# PHP Difference in secondi from a datetime value and now() with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In my php file i select from a mysql db a datetime field.
I need to know, in seconds (numeric value) the difference between this value and now()

e.g.:

value from db: 2014-02-02 16:58:22

Now is: 2014-02-03 16:59:00

Result: 86438

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try This http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2014-02-02 16:58:22', '2014-02-03 16:59:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate this in PHP, you can do this using the `DateTime` object

```
$First = new DateTime('2014-02-02 16:58:22');

$Second = new DateTime('2014-02-03 16:59:00');

echo "The difference is " . ($Second->getTimestamp() - $First->getTimestamp()) . " seconds";
```

Which will output:

```
The difference is 86438 seconds
```

Comment: I have tried but server say: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object (my func: $diff = ($b->getTimestamp() - $last['datet']->getTimestamp());)

Comment: $a=time();
$b=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);